# Samba AD DC not showing printers

Tags: windows, samba, printing, cups, samba4

I have setup my Ubuntu Server as an AD DC using Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu. When I try to access the printers share from a Windows Client I am getting an "Illegal Function" error. I tried it from Windows 10 and from Windows 7 Clients. Also the printers are not visible when I browse the server. CUPS is running and printing from CUPS works perfectly fine.

smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = WORK
        realm = WIN.WORK.COM
        netbios name = WORK-SERVER
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, smb
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver, winreg, srvsvc
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.smb
        log level = 10
        store dos attributes = yes
        use client driver = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/win.work.com/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba/print
        browseable = No
        public = Yes
        guest ok = Yes
        writable = No
        printable = Yes

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes

[Files]
   browseable = yes
   path = /media/Data
   create mask = 0700
   vfs objects = acl_xattr
   read only = no
   writable = yes
```

log.smb

```
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.548183,  5, pid=1543, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/winbind/wb_irpc.c:176(wb_irpc_get_idmap_callback)
  wb_irpc_get_idmap_callback called
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.548290,  5, pid=1543, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/winbind/wb_sids2xids.c:83(wb_sids2xids_recv)
  wb_sids2xids_recv called
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.548610,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/wbclient/wbclient.c:118(wbc_sids_to_xids_recv)
  wbc_sids_to_xids_recv called
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.548733,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/auth/unix_token.c:118(security_token_to_unix_token)
  Successfully converted security token to a unix token:Security token SIDs (14):
    SID[  0]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-500
    SID[  1]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-513
    SID[  2]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-520
    SID[  3]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-572
    SID[  4]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-519
    SID[  5]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-518
    SID[  6]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-512
    SID[  7]: S-1-5-21-3773313797-221468871-2936790298-1109
    SID[  8]: S-1-1-0
    SID[  9]: S-1-5-2
    SID[ 10]: S-1-5-11
    SID[ 11]: S-1-5-32-544
    SID[ 12]: S-1-5-32-545
    SID[ 13]: S-1-5-32-554
   Privileges (0x        1FFFFF80):
    Privilege[  0]: SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
    Privilege[  1]: SeBackupPrivilege
    Privilege[  2]: SeRestorePrivilege
    Privilege[  3]: SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege
    Privilege[  4]: SeDiskOperatorPrivilege
    Privilege[  5]: SeSecurityPrivilege
    Privilege[  6]: SeSystemtimePrivilege
    Privilege[  7]: SeShutdownPrivilege
    Privilege[  8]: SeDebugPrivilege
    Privilege[  9]: SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
    Privilege[ 10]: SeSystemProfilePrivilege
    Privilege[ 11]: SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege
    Privilege[ 12]: SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege
    Privilege[ 13]: SeLoadDriverPrivilege
    Privilege[ 14]: SeCreatePagefilePrivilege
    Privilege[ 15]: SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
    Privilege[ 16]: SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
    Privilege[ 17]: SeUndockPrivilege
    Privilege[ 18]: SeManageVolumePrivilege
    Privilege[ 19]: SeImpersonatePrivilege
    Privilege[ 20]: SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
    Privilege[ 21]: SeEnableDelegationPrivilege
   Rights (0x             403):
    Right[  0]: SeInteractiveLogonRight
    Right[  1]: SeNetworkLogonRight
    Right[  2]: SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.550663,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 319): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.550768,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] 0E CB 74 8D D2 0C 7E 07                            ..t...~.
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.550944, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.551053, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.551169,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] C1 F3 71 AB 85 DE 43 18                            ..q...C.
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.551309,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb/receive.c:500(switch_message)
  switch message SMBsplopen (task_id 1564)
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.551448,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 321): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.551547,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] B1 46 EE 9F FB 52 66 40                            .F...Rf@
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.557645, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.557832, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.557933,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] 50 08 03 58 7A 16 85 64                            P..Xz..d
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.558054,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb/receive.c:500(switch_message)
  switch message SMBsplopen (task_id 1564)
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.558184,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 323): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.558270,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] 81 88 6F 67 FA 78 C0 BC                            ..og.x..
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573331, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573505, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573587,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] B0 39 D7 CD E4 28 AE B0                            .9...(..
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573682,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb/receive.c:500(switch_message)
  switch message SMBsplopen (task_id 1564)
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573806,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 325): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.573899,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] FA FC 10 A7 79 6F 32 CE                            ....yo2.
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.578648, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.578909, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.579074,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] D0 72 2F 40 23 03 08 AA                            .r/@#...
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.579263,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb/receive.c:500(switch_message)
  switch message SMBsplopen (task_id 1564)
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.579452,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 327): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.579604,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] 9D 31 80 C5 97 81 D3 D0                            .1......
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.594430, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.594716, 10, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb_server.c:94(smbsrv_recv)
  smbsrv_recv
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.594890,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] 62 BC C8 E8 A1 7F C6 85                            b.......
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.595137,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/smb_server/smb/receive.c:500(switch_message)
  switch message SMBsplopen (task_id 1564)
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.595326,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source4/libcli/raw/smb_signing.c:107(sign_outgoing_message)
  sign_outgoing_message: SENT SIG (seq: 329): sent SMB signature of
[2015/10/05 15:56:18.595516,  5, pid=1564, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../lib/util/util.c:556(dump_data)
  [0000] B6 70 36 F7 B4 76 9A 57                            .p6..v.W
```